# Question about continuous not monotone function

Tags: functions, continuity

Consider a function $f$ that is continuous and not monotone. It can be proved that there exist $x,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f(x+d)$. How can I show that for all $d' \in (0,d)$ there exist an $x'$ such that $f(x')=f(x'+d')$?

This assumption is very intuitive when you look at the graph of a function however I can not formalize a proof. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxasl.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False !
Counter example :
Here $f(-3) = f(3)$ so it's okay for $d = 6$ but impossible for any $d' \in ]2, d[$
[image]